# Changing DGV checkboxes states according to DataTable

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, datatable, dataset

I have a `DataGridView` with two columns (one of these is a `CheckBox` type) and a `DataSet` with a `DataTable` constructed with a query result (with only one column). However, I want to check all checkboxes which name is on the `DataTable`:

```
name_col
--------
  A001
  A002
  A003
```

My final desired checkboxes status in `DataGridView` according to `DataTable` content:

```
checkbox_col | name_col
-----------------------
    X        |  A001   
    X        |  A002
    X        |  A003
             |  A004
             |  A005
```

However, I am getting a `MissingMemberException`  when I compare `dgv.DataSource` Item values and `DataTable` values. I have this code to check the boxes, according to `DataTable` content. I want to know what is my error and how to amend it. Thanks in advance (PD: `ds` is the `DataSet` containing the `DataTable`):

```
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count() > 0 Then
        For Each fon As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            For Each i As DataGridViewRow In Dgv.Rows
                If fon.Item(0) = Dgv.DataSource.Columns(0).Items.ToString() Then
                    i.Cells("col_check").Value = True
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a filled in DataGridView and you are comparing it to a DataTable from a different source. Your approach to loop through the DataTable and the grid is correct. Comparing the DataTable value to

```
Dgv.DataSource.Columns(0).Items.ToString()
```

does not make sense. You are going back to the original DataTable with the DataSource property, then Column 0 then the Items collection but a Column doesn't have an Items collection.

Looking at your DataGridView it seems that the column you want to compare is Cells(1) not Cells(0).

```
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count() > 0 Then
        For Each fon As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Dgv.Rows
                If fon(0).ToString = row.Cells(1).ToString() Then
                    row.Cells("col_check").Value = True
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
```

I don't have a grid with check boxes handy so I can't test the code.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had to change that and other thing in my code and now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had to make the change that @Mary suggested and adjust the used columns a bit:

```
                If fon(0).ToString = i.Cells(2).Value.ToString Then
                    i.Cells(0).Value = True
                End If
```